# Should I really go to Gehinnom if my wife tells me to?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Here's the scenario:

This year, my wife expected me to give her a huge diamond ring for her birthday. She didn't want any other gift.

I went to the jeweler, and request a 5 Karat Princess cut for my princess, but that size is back-ordered and he couldn't get it in time. My wife was really angry and told me to go to hell.

For the sake of Shalom Bayit, should I listen to her and really take her advice?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think the questions are degenerating. Just because it is Purim Torah should not give a license to ask any question. I think questions such as these are not appropriate.

Comment: @GershonGold - perhaps. Of course, the story is made up. You can vote to close. I have no problem with that.

Comment: I would prefer that you delete rather than I close.

Comment: This question sounds a bit misogynist to me, and the Jewish connection is tenuous. I don't think it's quite close-worthy, but I did downvote.

Comment: Sounds like you are already there.

Comment: Never seen a question with so many upvotes and downvotes. The community is split!

Comment: @Yehuda - Gehenimom divides people. I think people are more annoyed by the answers than the question. I won't comment on whether others have a wife like mine!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

She said hell, not Gehinnon.  Precision is important.

She is telling you to go to [Hell, CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell,_California) and try one of [these jewelers](http://www.primebuyersreport.org/ca/riverside-county-jewelry.html) in hopes you will be able to obtain better service.

If you leave now you should be able to present your princess with her due before Shabbat.

Comment: Have you ever been in Hell, CA?

Comment: I have not; everything I know about the place comes from the Internet.  Surely I can rely on that, right?

Answer (score 15):

She means go to hell, and from the fiery ovens forge her a ring.
Not three rings.
Not two rings.
Just one ring.

One ring to rule them all!

Comment: @Yitzchak LOL :)

Comment: That advice seems to "ring" a bell!

Comment: @DanF that will explain how whenever you want your wife, she's gone. She's put on the ring and gone invisible!

Answer (score 5):

No. The Gemara (:פסחים פו) says כל מה שיאמר לך בעה"ב עשה חוץ מצא- you must listen to everything the Baal Habayis tells you except "Tze"- "Leave". And if your home is like any classic Jewish home, then you know your wife is the real boss. Thus, you don't have to go anywhere!